# Multilingual sharepoint Site Creation - The Site definition I have developed does not appear to create site

Tags: sharepoint, multilingual, wss-3.0

I am new to Sharepoint.

Currently I am using VS 2005, WSS 3.0 for creating a site definition. My requirement is to create a site definition with master pages, web parts, etc... I have created a site definition in VS 2005 using team site definition option. deployed the developed site definition to sharepoint.

When I try to create site using the site definition I deployed in English version I am able to do so and working fine.

when I try to select German as Language (or any language), my site definition is not displayed there. (While it displays other previously created site definitions by others).

I have created Templates/1031/xml/webtemp....xml in my solution also for 1041 (for japanese).

I am clueless on what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed required language packs on SharePoint WFE Server?
Please check and it's must for each language.